# How to Store Java Epoch Long Value with Gremlin Python

Tags: python, java, gremlin

In my Apache Tinkerpop Gremlin based code I am using with AWS Neptune, need to share a timestamp field with Python based and Java based code bases in my project.
When I run the equivalent of the following code:

```
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import Cardinality

g.addV("xyzzy").
property(Cardinality.single, "when", datetime.now().timestamp() * 1000)
).
next()
```

But this causes number overflow exception and there seems to be no direct way to case a Phyton number to the Long value Java uses. How can I fix this so that I can store the same `Long` integer value that Java can use?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to use `gremlin_python.statics.long` to let Gremlin properly convert and store your Python based number value. Using your example, the code should be modified as following:

```
from gremlin_python.statics import long
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import Cardinality

g.addV("xyzzy").
property(Cardinality.single, "when", long(datetime.now().timestamp() * 1000)
).
next()
```

Also, for those using Neo4J or other Gremlin implementations, you usually not need to specify the `Cardinality.single.` That is AWS Neptune specific requirement.